# Use Python to draw sine waves with list or dictionary of turtle references

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, turtle-graphics

I tried to pull strings from a dictionary and wanted to iterate through them, in the wave function. The turtle should make a sine wave with the values of x and y. I tried with a list as well, but that didn't work. Maybe it's not possible and I'm going about the problem all wrong.

```
import turtle, math

def createTurtle(count):
    for x in range(count):
        turtle_dict[x] = turtle.Turtle()
        turtle_dict[x].shape("turtle")
        turtle_dict[x].color(color_list[x])
        turtle_dict[x].width(3)
        return turtle_dict[x]

def wave(count):
    for n in range(count):
        amp = amp_list[n]
        freq = freq_list[n]
        createTurtle(n)
        for x in range(361):
            y_val = amp * math.sin(math.radians(x * freq))
            turtle_dict.values().goto(x, y_val)
            print(x, y_val)

num_waves = int(input("How many sine waves do you want to create? "))
amp_list = []
freq_list = []
turtle_dict = {1 : "alpha", 2 : "beta", 3 : "gamma", 4 : "delta", 5 : "omega"}
color_list = ["red", "blue", "green", "purple", "pink"]
counter = 1

for x in range(num_waves):
    print("\nSine Wave #" , counter)
    amp = int(input("Enter the amplitude of the sine wave: "))
    freq = float(input("Enter the frequency of the sine wave: "))
    amp_list.append(amp)
    freq_list.append(freq)
    counter += 1

print(amp_list)
print(freq_list)
print(turtle_dict)

amp_screen = max(amp_list) + 1

win = turtle.Screen()
win.bgcolor("lightyellow")
win.setworldcoordinates(0,-amp_screen, 500 ,amp_screen)

wave(counter-1)

win.exitonclick()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My analysis is you can do this with a list -- you don't need a dictionary -- and the reason it doesn't work is that your code is very buggy.  For example, `createTurtle()` has an indentation error that causes it to return prematurely.  And where its called is incorrect, being passed a loop counter instead of the range of the loop.  The `turtle_dict` isn't used correctly, calling `goto()` on a list of turtles (`.values()`) instead of individual turtles.

Here's my rework to fix the problems I found and tweak the code style:

```
import math
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
from itertools import cycle

color_list = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'purple', 'pink']

def createTurtles(count):
    turtles = []
    colors = cycle(color_list)

    for _ in range(count):
        turtle = Turtle('turtle')
        turtle.color(next(colors))
        turtle.speed('fastest')
        turtle.width(3)

        turtles.append(turtle)

    return turtles

def wave(count):
    for n in range(count):
        amp = amp_list[n]
        freq = freq_list[n]
        turtle = turtles_list[n]
        turtle.penup()

        for x in range(361):
            y_val = amp * math.sin(math.radians(x * freq))
            turtle.goto(x, y_val)
            turtle.pendown()

num_waves = int(input('How many sine waves do you want to create? '))

amp_list = []
freq_list = []
counter = 1

for x in range(num_waves):
    print('\nSine Wave #', counter)
    amp = int(input('Enter the amplitude of the sine wave: '))
    freq = float(input('Enter the frequency of the sine wave: '))
    amp_list.append(amp)
    freq_list.append(freq)
    counter += 1

amp_screen = max(amp_list) + 1

screen = Screen()
screen.bgcolor('lightyellow')
screen.setworldcoordinates(0, -amp_screen, 400, amp_screen)

turtles_list = createTurtles(num_waves)

wave(counter - 1)

screen.exitonclick()
```

[image]

Comment: Ah that makes more sense. For the wave function, I didn't know you could iterate a list by assigning it to a variable. Thanks for the clarification! Just wondering, would it be possible to reference an entire wave? Say I want to add or subtract two waves.